# How to use multiple sql statements in a mysql event?

Tags: mysql, sql, events

These are the statements

```
INSERT INTO toolate (name,type,date) 
SELECT  name, type ,date 
FROM homework 
WHERE date < CURRENT_DATE()
```

and

```
DELETE FROM homework WHERE date < CURRENT_DATE()
```

I need to combine these two so that my event will work in a proper order.
Firstly the INSERT statement then the DELETE one.

That way I can still see homework that's past date while having a clean homework table and it needs to happen automatically thus why I'm using events. Of course I will welcome a different solution.

Comment: This is a really bad design #justsaying

Comment: @JohnHC points out that you can leave your old records in their original table, and retrieve current records with a view mentioning `date < CURRENT_DATE()`. He's right. The only reason to move rows from one table to another is when you have many millions of stale rows of data to put into archives.

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine these two in a single query. However, an alternative would be to use `STORED PROCEDURE` and execute these two inside a `transaction` with `EXIT HANDLER` e.g.:

```
BEGIN

    START TRANSACTION;

        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 

        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
            EXIT PROCEDURE;
        END;

        INSERT INTO toolate (name,type,date) 
        SELECT  name, type ,date 
        FROM homework 
        WHERE date < CURRENT_DATE()

        DELETE FROM homework WHERE date < CURRENT_DATE()

    COMMIT;
END
```

This will make sure both of these queries are executed sequencially, and if `DELETE` query fails, `INSERT` will be rolled back.

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html)'s MtSQL's documentation for stored procedures.